# Xcode/Parse - PFQuery NSMutableArray issue

Tags: xcode, arrays, parsing, nsmutablearray

[It may be a noob question but I've spent a lot of time to solve this issue.]

Basically, I am using www.parse.com services to store my data in the cloud. I'm retrieving a NSArray called objects, and its result in the console is:

```
2013-03-25 19:59:06.118 app[18960:c07] (
"<users:u8WRDUlfVg:(null)> {\n    pairs =     (\n        14120151,\n        14749606,\n        17230018\n    );\n    username = GeoffroyMorel;\n}"
)
```

Then, since I want the "pairs" values in an NSMutableArray, I'm doing this:

```
pairsUserMutableArray = [objects mutableArrayValueForKey:@"pairs"];
```

The result in console is pretty good, except an additional pair of parenthesis (which may be the reason of the following problem):

```
2013-03-25 19:59:06.119 app[18960:c07] (
    (
    14120151,
    14749606,
    17230018
)
)
```

Now the problem, when I'm trying to add an object, and show the result in the console it goes with parenthesis like this:

```
2013-03-25 20:02:45.887 app[18960:c07] (
    (
            (
        14120151,
        14749606,
        17230018
    ),
    15749606
)
)
```

I want it like this:

```
2013-03-25 20:02:45.887 app[18960:c07] (
    14120151,
    14749606,
    17230018,
    15749606
)
```

Thanks for your help, I'm sure I'm just missing a line that could order my NSMutableArray properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just found the answer, I hadn't noticed that the "objects" received form the query is an NSArray ! All you need is this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Users"];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:userAccount.username];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", objects);

    NSArray *array = [objects objectAtIndex:0];//Selects the first "object" from all the "objects"
    array = [array valueForKey:@"pairs"];//Makes a NSArray from the "pairs" values
    pairs = [array mutableCopy];//Converts the array to a NSMutableArray

    NSLog(@"%@, %i", pairs, pairs.count);
} else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
}];
```